# Is there a way to -not- refresh the page when we click on a link in SharePoint Web part?

Tags: web-part, connected-web-parts, 2007

A few days ago I submitted this question to stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161708/sharepoints-new-folder-doesnt-ask-for-a-required-field

I essentially have Web Part Connections filter some documents through a required field. I was having problems making that new field for the folders. I managed to do it with help from a user over there.

It is all good and dandy, but now my problem is that whenever someone goes into the folder, the filter gets reset, and you're not able to re-select the same option you were just at. We were very confused for a few minutes when we were playing with it. Does anyone know a solution for this? perhaps a different kind of filter that would allow this? It is pretty important that the filter doesn't refresh when we go into the folder.

Thanks! -V

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid a reset you will need to find some way to create a custom solution with ajax that is able to interact with the server without doing a post-back.

Comment: could this be doable with SharePoint designer? I've no experience with ajax, but I'll look into it.

Comment: ajax is a javascript library for client side script, so yes you could do this in SP Designer.  It may be pretty difficult if you are not familiar with ajax.  You would need to be very comfortable with javascript and the concept of calling web services.